# How to get PR Curves for Tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection-api

I want to evaluate model of my object detection API by using PR curves? can any one please help me with this?

I used same code

https://www.edureka.co/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-tutorial/

need Precission and recall curves for tensor flow object detection API
build on SSD coco model

Comment: Is PR curves used for classification task? For object detection task, the evaluation metric is mean average precision.

Comment: For evaluation of the model to know how far the model is good. and to which we apply on any image? not talking about the prediction probability of an object. if any thing is wrong in this please correct me @danyfang

Comment: You can check this out to see if this is what you needed. http://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval